# How to update record using multiple conditions in CollectionFactory magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, quote, resource-model, factory

I am trying to update the record but it creates a new record.

Collection factory

```
     <?php


namespace Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Block;

use Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\ResourceModel\Quoteconversation;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data;
use Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\QuotesFactory;
use Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\SellerQuotesFactory;
use Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\QuoteconversationFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\ResourceModel\SellerQuotes;


class Mpeditquotes extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var customerSession
     */
    protected $_customerSession;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
     */
    protected $_customerModel;
    /**
     * @var quoteCollection
     */
    protected $_quoteConversationCollection;
    /**
     * @var pricingHelper
     */
    protected $_pricingHelper;
    /**
     * @var _quotesFactory
     */
    protected $_quotesFactory;
    /**
     * @var _sellerQuoteFactory
     */
    protected $_sellerQuoteFactory;
    /**
     * @var _productFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $_imageHelper;
    /**
     * @var _quoteConversationCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_quoteConversationCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var _quoteconversationFactory
     */
    protected $_quoteconversationFactory;
    protected $_sellercolletcionquotes;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session        $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer       $customerModel
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param Quoteconversation\CollectionFactory    $conversationCollectionFactory
     * @param QuotesFactory                          $_quotesFactory
     * @param ProductFactory                         $productFactory
     * @param QuoteconversationFactory               $conversationFactory
     * @param Data                                   $pricingHelper
     * @param array                                  $data
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerModel,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        Quoteconversation\CollectionFactory $conversationCollectionFactory,
        QuotesFactory $_quotesFactory,
        SellerQuotesFactory $sellerQuoteFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        QuoteconversationFactory $conversationFactory,
        \Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\ResourceModel\SellerQuotes\CollectionFactory $sellercolletcionquotes,
        Data $pricingHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_customerModel = $customerModel;
        $this->_quoteConversationCollectionFactory = $conversationCollectionFactory;
        $this->_pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
        $this->_quotesFactory = $_quotesFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_sellerQuoteFactory = $sellerQuoteFactory;
        $this->_quoteconversationFactory = $conversationFactory;
        $this->_imageHelper = $context->getImageHelper();
        $this->_sellercolletcionquotes = $sellercolletcionquotes;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getQuoteConversationCollection()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
                'mpquotesystem.pager'
            )
            ->setCollection(
                $this->getQuoteConversationCollection()
            );
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getQuoteConversationCollection()->load();
        }

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
    /**
     * customer Id by customer session.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
    }
    /**
     * customer data by customer id.
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getCustomerData($customerId)
    {
        return $this->_customerModel->load($customerId);
    }
    /**
     * get Collection of quotes conversation for particular quote id.
     *
     * @return collection
     */
    public function getQuoteConversationCollection()
    {
        if (!$this->_quoteConversationCollection) {
            $sellerquoteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
             $sellerquote = $this->getSellerQuotes($sellerquoteId);
             $quoteId = $sellerquote->getQuoteId();
             $sellerId = $sellerquote->getSellerId();
            if ($quoteId != 0) {
                $collection = $this->_quoteConversationCollectionFactory
                    ->create()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $quoteId)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('sender', $sellerId);

                $this->_quoteConversationCollection = $collection;
            }
        }

        return $this->_quoteConversationCollection;
    }
    /**
     * get formatted price by currency.
     *
     * @return format price string
     */
    public function getFormattedPrice($price)
    {
        return $this->_pricingHelper
            ->currency($price, true, false);
    }

    public function getQuoteData($entityId)
    {
        $quoteModel = $this->_quotesFactory->create()->load($entityId);
        return $quoteModel;
    }
    /**
     * get Collection of quotes conversation for particular quote id.
     *
     * @return collection
     */
    public function getsellerQuoteConversationCollection($quoteId)
    {

        if (!$this->_quoteConversationCollection) {
            //~ $quoteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($quoteId != 0) {
                $collection = $this->_quoteConversationCollectionFactory
                    ->create()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $quoteId);

                $this->_quoteConversationCollection = $collection;
            }
        }

        return $this->_quoteConversationCollection;
    }


  /**  public function **getsellerupdateCollection**($quoteId,$sellerid)
    {


        //~ $quoteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($quoteId != 0) {
            $collection = $this->_sellercolletcionquotes
                ->create()

                ->load('quote_id',$quoteId)
                ->load('main_table.status',array('in'=>array('1','2')))
                ->load('main_table.seller_id',['neq'=>$sellerid])
                ->load('main_table.nstatus',1);

          foreach($collection as $item) {

          }
            $this->_sellercolletcionquotes = $collection;

        }


        return $this->_sellercolletcionquotes;
    }*/

   public function getsellerupdateCollection($quoteId,$sellerid)
   {


       //~ $quoteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
       if ($quoteId != 0) {
           $collection = $this->_sellercolletcionquotes
               ->create()
               ->addFieldToSelect('quote_id', $quoteId)
               ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status', array('in' => array('1', '2')))
               ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.seller_id', ['neq' => $sellerid])
               ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.nstatus', 1);



           foreach($collection as $item)
           {
                $item->setNstatus('Sold');
           $item->save();

           }

       $this->_sellercolletcionquotes = $collection;
       }
    return $this->_sellercolletcionquotes;
    }


    public function getSellerQuotes($entityId){
        $quoteModel = $this->_sellerQuoteFactory->create()->load($entityId);
        return $quoteModel;
    }
    public function getProductData($productId)
    {
        $productModel = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        return $productModel;
    }
    public function imageHelperObj()
    {
        return $this->_imageHelper;
    }
    public function getProductPriceHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $priceType = \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
        $renderZone = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
        array $arguments = []
    ) {
        if (!isset($arguments['zone'])) {
            $arguments['zone'] = $renderZone;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
        $price = '';

        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render($priceType, $product, $arguments);
        }
        return $price;
    }

    public function getParameters()
    {
        return $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    }


    /**
     * getIsSecure check is secure or not
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsSecure()
    {
        return $this->getRequest()->isSecure();
    }
    /**
     * check whether a quote is sold or not?
     * @param  int $quoteStatus
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function quoteStatusIsNotSold($quoteStatus)
    {
        if ($quoteStatus!=\Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\Quotes::STATUS_SOLD) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

> I want multiple where a condition for update record in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

I have updated a few lines of code.

```
public function getsellerupdateCollection($quoteId,$sellerid)
{
    if ($quoteId != 0) {
        $collection = $this->_sellercolletcionquotes
            ->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('quote_id',$quoteId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status',array('in'=>array('1','2')))
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.seller_id',['neq'=>$sellerid])
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.nstatus',1);

        foreach($collections as $item)
        {
           $item->setNstatus('Sold');
           $item->save();
        }
        $this->_sellercolletcionquotes = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_sellercolletcionquotes;
}
```

Comment: i will  check .....................

Comment: Why you are adding condition like this ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.seller_id',['neq'=>$sellerid]) instead of ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.seller_id',['eq'=>$sellerid])

Comment: i am omitting that customer for update...

Comment: ok is that worked?

Comment: Actaully, what you want update it

Comment: no it  creates new  record not updating 

(empty records )

Comment: based on quote_id
i want to update the **nstatus**

Comment: I have updated my code. Please check it now.

Comment: i already defined in constract \Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\ResourceModel\SellerQuotes\CollectionFactory $sellercolletcionquotes,

Comment: Please post your updated code so I will help you

Comment: @prabhakaran7 Please used collection factory instead of collection

Comment: i updated my file (Code) ....

Comment: Please added ->getCollection()

Comment: why i can  add  getCollection

Comment: Because of load current model data based on filter

Comment: but showing exception Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method in Resource model Collection::getCollection() in /var/www/html/*

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, adding `getCollection()`:

```
public function getsellerupdateCollection($quoteId,$sellerid)
{
    if ($quoteId != 0) {
        $collection = $this->_sellercolletcionquotes
            ->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('quote_id',$quoteId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status',array('in'=>array('1','2')))
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.seller_id',['neq'=>$sellerid])
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.nstatus',1);

        foreach($collections as $item)
        {
           $item->setNstatus('Sold');
           $item->save();
        }
        $this->_sellercolletcionquotes = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_sellercolletcionquotes;
}
```

Comment: where i    can use   save();   -   method

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method    in  Resource model
Collection::getCollection() in  /var/www/html/*

Comment: i already     defined in constract

\Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\ResourceModel\SellerQuotes\CollectionFactory $sellercolletcionquotes,

Comment: @prabhakaran7 Please used collection factory instead of collection

Comment: run upgrade @prabhakaran7

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\ResourceModel\SellerQuotes\Collection::setNstatus() in /var/www/html/equpo2/app/code/Webkul/Mpquotesystem/Block/Mpeditquotes.php on line 257

after upgrading

Comment: maybe setStatus instead

Comment: @prabhakaran7 did you resolve it?

Comment: @prabhakaran7  how about using `sellerQuoteFactory` instead of `_sellercolletcionquotes`

Comment: yah i changed it in all places

Comment: @prabhakaran7 did it work?

Comment: i make  mistake    ** ->addFieldToSelect('quote_id',$quoteId)**

addFieldsToFIlter  instead  select

Comment: cool haha nice to see it\

Comment: yah...................